# How do I remove first-child and last-child class from <li> in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<div class="containerPersonal">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdownPersonal first-child"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownPersonal">Home<i class="iconArrow"></i></a></li>
      <li class="dropdownPersonal"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownPersonal">Events<i class="iconArrow"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I remove the class "first-child" and "last-child"from my "li" tag, whitch are dyinamical generated when I add items to my navigation menu ?
I searched in functions.php, nav-menu-template.php, nav-menus.php and didn`t find anything.
I don`t want to remove the classes with a javascript code !!

Comment: You could probably do this via a filter. Question is *why*? If you don't apply any styles to the class what harm is it causing?

Comment: @Dre : I have my own class "dropdownPersonal" and I don`t need others.

Answer (score 3):

To contribute further to the first answer, if you're wanting to do this easily, unless you're using a framework such as angular, then jQuery is your second best option to filter this class.

But.. why would you want to remove a class that has no impact? If it's for code efficiency (removing a class that's un-needed) - resulting in shorter code - then the amount of code required to 'snip' this class from the element is going to be more than the "first-child" class anyway, if word-press is applying styling you don't want to these classes then it would make more sense to remove this styling rather than remove the class, as theoretically they are the first and last child respectively in the list and should be kept as such?